# Total cpu utilization of running app engine flexible instances

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver, app-engine-flexible

I need to make decisions in an external system based on the current CPU utilization of my App Engine Flexible service. I can see the exact values / metrics I need to use in the dashboard charting in my Google Cloud Console, but I don't see a direct, easy way to get this information from something like a `gcloud` command.

I also need to know the count of running instances, but I think I can use `gcloud app instances list -s default` to get a list of my running instances in the default service, and then I can use a count of lines approach to get this info easily. I intend to make a python function which returns a tuple like `(instance_count, cpu_utilization)`.

I'd appreciate if anyone can direct me to an *easy* way to get this. I am currently exploring the StackDriver Monitoring service to get this same information, but as of now it is looking super-complicated to me.

Answer (score 1):

You  can use the `gcloud app instances list -s default` command to get the running instances list, as you said. To retrieve CPU utilization, have a look on this [Python Client for Stackdriver Monitoring](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/monitoring). To list available metric types:

```
from google.cloud import monitoring
client = monitoring.Client()
for descriptor in client.list_metric_descriptors():
   print(descriptor.type)
```

Metric descriptors are described [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/monitoring/usage.html#metric-descriptors). To display utilization across your GCE instances during the last five minutes:

```
metric = 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization'
query = client.query(metric, minutes=5)
print(query.as_dataframe())
```

Do not forget to add `google-cloud-monitoring==0.28.1` to “requirements.txt” before installing it.

Check this code that locally runs for me:

```
import logging

from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import monitoring as mon

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def list_metric_descriptors():
    """Return all metric descriptors"""
    # Instantiate client 
    client = mon.Client()

    for descriptor in client.list_metric_descriptors():
        print(descriptor.type)
    return descriptor.type

@app.route('/CPU')
def cpuUtilization():
    """Return CPU utilization"""
    client = mon.Client()
    metric = 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization'
    query = client.query(metric, minutes=5)
    print(type(query.as_dataframe()))    
    print(query.as_dataframe())    
    data=str(query.as_dataframe())
    return data

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return """
    An internal error occurred: <pre>{}</pre>
    See logs for full stacktrace.
    """.format(e), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entrypoint in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```